how to fix btusb 4.1 incompatibility with Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS kernel 6.8.0-50-generic
While updating the kernel from 6.8.0-49-generic to 6.8.0-50-generic, I experienced errors with the bluetooth driver installed from https://github.com/jeremyb31/bluetooth-6.8. This was the error message:
Building module:
Cleaning build area...
'make' all KVER=6.8.0-50-generic...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for btusb: 4.1 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.8.0-50-generic(x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/btusb/4.1/build/make.log for more information.
dkms autoinstall on 6.8.0-50-generic/x86_64 failed for btusb(10)
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
    dkms: autoinstall for kernel 6.8.0-50-generic...fail!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-6.8.0-50-generic(--configure):
installed linux-headers-6.8.0-50-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 11
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-generic:
linux-headers-generic depends on linux-headers-6.8.0-50-generic; however:
Package linux-headers-6.8.0-50-generic is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-generic (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
Processing triggers for linux-image-6.8.0-50-generic (6.8.0-50.51) .../etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
    dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.8.0-50-generic
Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign
Signing key: /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der
Building module:
Cleaning build area...
'make' all KVER=6.8.0-50-generic...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for btusb: 4.1 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.8.0-50-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/btusb/4.1/build/make.log for more information.
dkms autoinstall on 6.8.0-50-generic/x86_64 failed for btusb(10)
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
    dkms: autoinstall for kernel 6.8.0-50-generic...fail!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.8.0-50-generic (--configure):
installed linux-image-6.8.0-50-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 11
Errors were encountered while processing:
linux-headers-6.8.0-50-generic
linux-headers-generic
linux-image-6.8.0-50-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I've dkms removed btusb/4.1 -all, cloned the github repo, and tried to dkms install btusb 4.1 again but encountered the same error. the following is the content of the make.log:
DKMS make.log for btusb-4.1 for kernel 6.8.0-50-generic (x86_64)
Wed Dec 11 09:52:35 PM +08 2024
make -C /lib/modules/6.8.0-50-generic/build M=/var/lib/dkms/btusb/4.1/build modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.8.0-50-generic'
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
The kernel was built by: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-13 (Ubuntu 13.3.0-6ubuntu2~24.04) 13.3.0
You are using: gcc-13 (Ubuntu 13.2.0-23ubuntu4) 13.2.0
CC [M] /var/lib/dkms/btusb/4.1/build/btusb.o
/var/lib/dkms/btusb/4.1/build/btusb.c: In function ‘btusb_probe’:
/var/lib/dkms/btusb/4.1/build/btusb.c:4501:25: error: ‘HCI_QUIRK_VALID_LE_STATES’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘HCI_QUIRK_BROKEN_LE_STATES’?
4501 | set_bit(HCI_QUIRK_VALID_LE_STATES, &hdev->quirks);
  |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  |                         HCI_QUIRK_BROKEN_LE_STATES
/var/lib/dkms/btusb/4.1/build/btusb.c:4501:25: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:243: /var/lib/dkms/btusb/4.1/build/btusb.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-6.8.0-50-generic/Makefile:1925: /var/lib/dkms/btusb/4.1/build] Error 2
make[1]: *** [Makefile:240: __sub-make] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.8.0-50-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:7: all] Error 2

Currently, I'm without bluetooth in order to upgrade to 6.8.0-50. Are there any alternative solution to getting bluetooth to work?

See https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=2561519#p2561519

Thanks Jeremy, the solution to install btusb/4.2 using the -b 6.5-50 worked. How do I keep myself informed on updates bluetooth-6.8 to the repo?

The real problem is that I don't know of the issue before they happen, someone has to report it
